# C# code confusion of where clause

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

```
public interface ICrudService<T> where T: Entity, new()
```

What is the meaning of "`new()`" at the end of the above code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`new()` means that `T` has to have a parameterless constructor.

This is a help to enable you to construct objects of type `T` in your generic class/method:

```
public T Create()
{
   return new T();
}
```